# Images are not caching using Glide

Tags: android, android-glide

I am using Glide to load images and OkHttp3 library for networking as I am fetching images form node server.I want to cache images so that they do not load from network when activity opens every time.
Whenever activity opens it starts fetching data from network I simply want to cache data and whenever new image upload on server it should load data from network.

I am using this code below to cache image but it seems nothing is happening.

```
 RequestOptions requestOptions = new RequestOptions();
 requestOptions.placeholder(R.drawable.openbook);
 requestOptions.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE);

 Glide.with(context).load(model.getImage()).apply(requestOptions).into(slideImage);
```

Let me know some possible solution of my problem any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Try changing `DiskCacheStrategy.RESOURCE` to `DiskCacheStrategy.ALL`. BTW, judging from your strategy, why don`t you save the images and load them in your activity instead of making network calls repeatedly? You could save a count of all images downloaded and on activity start you could compare the counts from your disk to the counts received from the network and then do the desired action?

Comment: @Taseer, It seems your solution is fine but how can I implement the same please provide me with code.